# Действительно ли "блин" — аналог матерного слова?

Tags: этимология, жаргон

Скажите, пожалуйста, это правда, что слово "блин", ставшее уже просто междометием, — это действительно заменитель слова на ту же букву?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В одном из значений - да, возглас раздражения, действительно является эвфемизмом, замещающим любое слово, выражающее сильную эмоцию,и ругательство в том числе, а бывает, что употребляется и просто для связки слов без смысловой нагрузки: http://teenslang.su/content/%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD&slang=all
http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD